# Doctrine2 ODM QueryBuilder - Update field with sum of two fields

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, query-builder, doctrine-odm

Basically try to do the same as:

```
UPDATE table SET column3 = column1 + column2;
```

In the Doctrine2's ODM QueryBuilder - is something like this possible with out MapReduce? I have a sharded collection, so I need to use the QueryBuilder in order to search by my compound shard key.

Simplified exmaple:

```
$visit = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder('Visit')
   ->findAndUpdate()
   ->field('site')->equals( $site )
   ->field('timeStamp')->equals( $ts )
   ->field('_id')->equals( $id )
   ->update()
   ->field('column3')->set( 'column1 + column2' );
```

Unfortunately, that would set `column3` to the string "column1 + column2". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, neither `$inc` nor `$set` will help here, as they expect literal values. I also don't think [findAndModify](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command) would help, since it uses the same modifier object as `update()`.

I don't think map/reduce is appropriate either, as that isn't intended to modify the documents being mapped.

If you weren't in a sharded infrastructure, you could use [db.eval()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-Sharding) to fetch and update the object atomically; however, that isn't an option.

I would suggest splitting this into two queries. First, find the object by its `site`, `timestamp` and `_id`. You can limit the fields returned to `column1` and `column2`. Then, issue an update with the same criteria *plus* a match on `column1` and `column2`, and set `column3` to their sum. The addition of `column1` and `column2` to the update criteria will ensure you don't inadvertently store an invalid if those fields were changed between the find and update queries. And effectively, your update query becomes [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Yeah, I was hoping to avoid a second query - but your approach makes sense.